# IBM WorkLight Error "Ajax request exception: There is no application in the DB with the id 'Todo'. [project TodoProject]"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am using SQL adapter in worklight and getting "Ajax request exception: There is no application in the DB with the id 'Todo'. [project TodoProject]".

In the past it was working fine.

Please help me resolve this error.

-Ashwini

Comment: It would be better if you share the code so that we can try to analyse. with only error which says exceptions how we will help you?

Comment: also share which version of Worklight you are using? is it happening in Developement environment or in production ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your application is deployed?

If you are in the Worklight Development Server (Worklight Studio Eclipse plug-in), right-click on your application folder and select Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server.

If you are using an external application server, verify you have deployed your application's .wlapp file (located in the \bin folder in Eclipse) via Worklight Console.

Otherwise, take some time edit your question with more information, like what you've done "in the past that it worked well".

Comment: thanks Idan, I have redeployed my application and it is working fine know thank you.

Comment: Idan thanks for letting me know.I got one more Question for you.